# работа уведомлений когда приложение свернуто

Tags: ios, swift, уведомления, push-уведомления

Я не знаю, движусь ли я в правильном направлении, но для начала работы уведомлений в фоновом режиме я создал таймер с периодичностью экшна раз в минуту:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Затем передаю данные в мои уведомления:

```
@objc func timerAction() {
UserNotificationManager.shared.addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(title: "aaa", identifier: "bbb", subTitle: "ddd", body: "sss")}
```

Насколько я понимаю, затем я должен это все связать как-то в `Appdelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, где у меня есть функции для  уведомлений:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UserNotificationManager.shared.registerNotification()
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    return true
}
```

В общем, как мне реализовать работу уведомлений раз в минуту в фоновом режиме, если приложение свернуто?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer не будет срабатывать после сворачивания приложения. Для таких целей необходимо использовать `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`

Подробности в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger), пример:

```
// Fire in 30 minutes (60 seconds times 30)
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (30*60), repeats: false) // Для повторяющегося - repeats: true
```

Comment: Спасибо и Благодарочка)

Comment: А можно как то выполнять функцию в фоне например каждые 24 часа? Просто читал, не знаю о какой версии свифта, что в фоне приложение живет 5 мин